# Boost:Take seconds/milli/micro/nano of how long a function runs

Tags: c++, boost

I basically have a school project testing the time it takes different sort algorithms and record how long they take with n amount of numbers to sort. So I decided to use Boost library with c++ to record the time. I am at the point I am not sure how to do it, I have googled it and have found people using different ways. for examples

```
auto start = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto end = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto time = (end-start).count();
```

or

```
boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

or

```
boost::chrono::steady_clock::now()
```

or even using something like this

```
boost::timer::cpu_timer and boost::timer::auto_cpu_time
```

or

```
boost::posix_time::ptime start = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time( );
```

so I want to be sure on how to do it right now this is what I have

```
typedef boost::chrono::duration<double, boost::nano> boost_nano;

auto start_t = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// call function
auto end_t = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
boost_nano time = (end_t - start_t);
cout << t.count();
```

so am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

You likely want the high resolution timer.

You can use either that of `boost::chrono` or `std::chrono`.

Boost Chrono has some support for IO builtin, so it makes it easier to report times in a human friendly way.

I usually use a wrapper similar to this:

```
template <typename Caption, typename F>
auto timed(Caption const& task, F&& f) {
    using namespace boost::chrono;
    struct _ {
        high_resolution_clock::time_point s;
        Caption const& task;
        ~_() { std::cout << " -- (" << task << " completed in " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - s) << ")\n"; }
    } timing { high_resolution_clock::now(), task };

    return f();
}
```

Which reports time taken in milliseconds.

The good part here is that you can time construction and similar:

```
std::vector<int> large = timed("generate data", [] {
           return generate_uniform_random_data(); });
```

But also, general code blocks:

```
timed("do_step2", [] {
    // step two is foo and bar:
    foo();
    bar();
});
```

And it works if e.g. foo() throws, just fine.

### DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e2936c8504025d4)</kbd>**

```
int main() {
    return timed("demo task", [] {
        sleep(1);
        return 42; 
    });
}
```

Prints

```
 -- (demo task completed in 1000 milliseconds)
42
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) or [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) (if it is steady - see below) and not [`std::chrono::system_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) for measuring run time in C++11 (or use its boost equivalent). The reason is (quoting `system_clock`'s documentation):

> on most systems, the system time can be adjusted at any moment

while steady_clock is monotonic and is better suited for measuring intervals:

> Class std::chrono::steady_clock represents a monotonic clock. The time
>   points of this clock cannot decrease as physical time moves forward.
>   This clock is not related to wall clock time, and is best suitable for
>   measuring intervals.

Here's an example:

```
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
// do something
auto finish = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
double elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<
  std::chrono::duration<double> >(finish - start).count();
```

A small practical tip: if you are measuring run time and want to report seconds `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>` is rarely what you need because it gives you *whole* number of seconds. To get the time in seconds as a `double` use the example above.

As suggested by Gregor McGregor, you can use a `high_resolution_clock` which may sometimes provide higher resolution (although it can be an alias of `steady_clock`), but beware that it may also be an alias of `system_clock`, so you might want to check `is_steady`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am still new at this and would like some explanation,

what is time points?

what do you mean by wall clock time?

and can you post a sample of how to implement this?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. The OP wants to measure very shorts interval of time with nanosecond precision so it's better to recommend `high_resolution_clock` instead of `steady_clock`, which `high_resolution_clock` may be an alias of anyway.

Comment: @TannerSummers I've added an example. Hope it helps. Wall clock time is the actual "real world" time as opposed to CPU time.

Comment: time(0) (and the newer equivalents) returns wall clock time (the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970, check this factoid, I seldom use it).  There exists a conversion (in Linux, and c++11) function to extract from the time_t returned the broken-down-time (yr, mo, day, hr, min, sec).

Comment: @GregorMcGregor, and vitaut thanks guys, is the time seconds by default? I need it in other formats along as a floating point number :)

Comment: @TannerSummers The example in my answer shows how to get seconds (as a double) but you can use duration_cast to get other units e.g. milliseconds.

Comment: @vitaut thank you, you said, " but you can use duration_cast to get other units e.g. milliseconds" can I also get those in floating points?

Comment: @TannerSummers Yes, std::chrono::duration<double> gives seconds as a floating-point (double) number.

Comment: @vitaut I meant get mili, nano , etc as floating point, can I cast it as nano seconds and cast it as double to get the nano as a floating point?

thank you so much btw and sorry for all the questions

Comment: @TannerSummers Yes, you can do it, e.g. by using `std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>` instead of `std::chrono::duration<double>` above to get milliseconds. Similarly for nano- etc.

Comment: @vitaut I am getting a compile error using 

std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double, std::chrono::nanoseconds>>(t2 - t1);

I will report back when I figure it out

Comment: @TannerSummers The second template argument should be std::nano, not std::chrono::nanoseconds. Or you can cast to std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::nanoseconds> and get integer number of nanoseconds.

Comment: hey @vitaut sorry for long wait on replying, I had mid terms, anyways this is what I currently have 

boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::duration<double, boost::nano>>(start-end)

and then i have this

time_span.count() << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << std::endl;

but my answers all come out as, xxxxxx.0000000

nothing on the right side of the decimal, where could the problem be?

Comment: You don't get anything on the right-hand side probably because nanoseconds is a very small unit probably less or equal to the timer resolution. So it can't give you a fraction of a nanosecond. Also I think it should be `end - start` instead of `start - end`.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use time(0) to control the duration of a loop.  time(0) is simply one time measurement that, because of its own short duration, has the least impact on everything else going on (and you can even run a do-nothing loop to capture how much to subtract from any other loop measurement effort).

So in a loop running for 3 (or 10 seconds), how many times can the loop invoke the thing you are trying to measure?

Here is an example of how my older code measures the duration of 'getpid()'

```
uint32_t spinPidTillTime0SecChange(volatile int& pid)
{
   uint32_t spinCount = 1; // getpid() invocation count

   // no measurement, just spinning
   ::time_t tStart = ::time(nullptr);
   ::time_t   tEnd = tStart;

   while (0 == (tEnd - tStart)) // (tStart == tEnd)
   {
      pid = ::getpid();
      tEnd = ::time(nullptr);
      spinCount += 1;
   }
   return(spinCount);
}
```

Invoke this 3 (or 10) times, adding the return values together.  To make it easy, discard the first measurement (because it probably will be a partial second).

Yes, I am sure there is a c++11 version of accessing what time(0) accesses.

Comment: On my desktop, std::time(nullptr) measures out to about 5 ns.  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() and steady_clock::now() measure to  more than 1000 ns.  Do not know why.  Perhaps because, in general, they are a more useful value?

Comment: You are probably using MSVC < 2015? `std::high_resolution_clock` is broken on those.

Comment: @GregorMcGregor - This morning, code unchanged, recompiled (-O0) unoptimized:   ::time(nullptr) measures ~7 ns.;  std::time(nullptr) - 9 ns.;  high_resolution - 1.1 us; steady_clock - 1.2 us;   on Ubuntu 15.10, c++ v5.2.1.  I installed 15.10 last week ... and still have plenty of minor-benchmark-code to investigate.   So far, best bogomips on this old Dell is 5122.